# Ubuntu Freezing due to wifi driver issues

Tags: 18.04, wireless, kernel, network-manager, iwlwifi

I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 for couple of months and suddenly my laptop started freezing randomly to the point it is a problem to normal usage. I have a dual boot with windows as the other OS and it works with no freezing problems. I tried to figure out what was wrong.
I found that the logs of the last boot can be accessed by the command

```
sudo journalctl -b -1 -e
```

The log shows that my wifi driver is having issues doing authentication on the network. Here is the dump of the relevant part.

```
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129, bcdDevice=39.60
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: checking bus 1, device 27: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4"
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: bus: 1, device: 27 was not an MTP device
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 27
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129, bcdDevice=39.60
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: checking bus 1, device 28: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4"
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: bus: 1, device: 28 was not an MTP device
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:23 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:41:23 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:d8:00:b7 failed
Nov 02 12:41:55 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:41:55 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:25:37 failed
Nov 02 12:42:27 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:42:27 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:27:c7 failed
Nov 02 12:42:59 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:42:59 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:1b:07 failed
Nov 02 12:43:26 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=65000
Nov 02 12:43:31 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:43:31 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:19:97 failed
Nov 02 12:43:38 thesunny kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (2518 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79250
Nov 02 12:44:03 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:44:03 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:24:a7 failed
Nov 02 12:44:35 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:44:35 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:d7:ff:c7 failed
Nov 02 12:45:07 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:45:07 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:26:e7 failed
Nov 02 12:45:39 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:45:39 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:d8:00:b7 failed
Nov 02 12:46:11 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:46:11 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:18:d7 failed
Nov 02 12:46:43 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:46:43 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:27:c7 failed
Nov 02 12:47:16 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:47:16 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:23:57 failed
Nov 02 12:47:48 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:47:48 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:1a:e7 failed
Nov 02 12:48:20 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:48:20 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:19:97 failed
lines 951-1004/1004 (END)
Nov 02 12:40:51 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication wi
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 27 us
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, i
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: checking bus 1, device 27: "/sys/devic
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: bus: 1, device: 27 was not an MTP devi
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 27
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/device
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/device
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 28 us
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, i
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: checking bus 1, device 28: "/sys/devic
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: bus: 1, device: 28 was not an MTP devi
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/
lines 951-973/1004 97%
Nov 02 12:40:51 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:23:57 failed
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129, bcdDevice=39.60
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: checking bus 1, device 27: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4"
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: bus: 1, device: 27 was not an MTP device
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 27
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129, bcdDevice=39.60
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: checking bus 1, device 28: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4"
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: bus: 1, device: 28 was not an MTP device
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:23 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session 
Nov 02 12:40:51 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication wi
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 27 us
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, i
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: checking bus 1, device 27: "/sys/devic
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: bus: 1, device: 27 was not an MTP devi
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 27
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/device
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/device
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 28 us
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, i
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: checking bus 1, device 28: "/sys/devic
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: bus: 1, device: 28 was not an MTP devi
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/
lines 951-973/1004 97%
Nov 02 12:40:51 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:23:57 failed
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129, bcdDevice=39.60
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: checking bus 1, device 27: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4"
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: bus: 1, device: 27 was not an MTP device
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 27
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129, bcdDevice=39.60
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: checking bus 1, device 28: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4"
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: bus: 1, device: 28 was not an MTP device
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:23 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:41:23 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:d8:00:b7 failed
Nov 02 12:41:55 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:41:55 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:25:37 failed
Nov 02 12:42:27 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:42:27 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:27:c7 failed
Nov 02 12:42:59 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:42:59 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:1b:07 failed
Nov 02 12:43:26 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=65000
Nov 02 12:43:31 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:43:31 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:19:97 failed
Nov 02 12:43:38 thesunny kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (2518 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79250
Nov 02 12:44:03 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:44:03 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:24:a7 failed
Nov 02 12:44:35 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:44:35 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:d7:ff:c7 failed
Nov 02 12:45:07 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:45:07 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:26:e7 failed
Nov 02 12:45:39 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:45:39 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:d8:00:b7 failed
Nov 02 12:46:11 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:46:11 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:18:d7 failed
Nov 02 12:46:43 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:46:43 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:27:c7 failed
Nov 02 12:47:16 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:47:16 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:23:57 failed
Nov 02 12:47:48 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:47:48 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:1a:e7 failed
Nov 02 12:48:20 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:48:20 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:19:97 failed
lines 951-1004/1004 (END)
Nov 02 12:40:51 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication wi
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 27 us
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, i
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: checking bus 1, device 27: "/sys/devic
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: bus: 1, device: 27 was not an MTP devi
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 27
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/device
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/device
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 28 us
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, i
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: checking bus 1, device 28: "/sys/devic
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: bus: 1, device: 28 was not an MTP devi
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/
lines 951-973/1004 97%
Nov 02 12:40:51 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:23:57 failed
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129, bcdDevice=39.60
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: checking bus 1, device 27: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4"
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny mtp-probe[5835]: bus: 1, device: 27 was not an MTP device
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:08 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 27
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129, bcdDevice=39.60
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: checking bus 1, device 28: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4"
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny mtp-probe[5850]: bus: 1, device: 28 was not an MTP device
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Nov 02 12:41:09 thesunny upowerd[1165]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
Nov 02 12:41:23 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:41:23 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:d8:00:b7 failed
Nov 02 12:41:55 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:41:55 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:25:37 failed
Nov 02 12:42:27 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:42:27 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:27:c7 failed
Nov 02 12:42:59 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:42:59 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:1b:07 failed
Nov 02 12:43:26 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=65000
Nov 02 12:43:31 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:43:31 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:19:97 failed
Nov 02 12:43:38 thesunny kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (2518 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79250
Nov 02 12:44:03 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:44:03 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:24:a7 failed
Nov 02 12:44:35 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:44:35 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:d7:ff:c7 failed
Nov 02 12:45:07 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:45:07 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:26:e7 failed
Nov 02 12:45:39 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:45:39 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:d8:00:b7 failed
Nov 02 12:46:11 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:46:11 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:18:d7 failed
Nov 02 12:46:43 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:46:43 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:27:c7 failed
Nov 02 12:47:16 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:47:16 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:23:57 failed
Nov 02 12:47:48 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:47:48 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:1a:e7 failed
Nov 02 12:48:20 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: failed to get master session key from pre-auth EAPOL state machines
Nov 02 12:48:20 thesunny wpa_supplicant[939]: wlp3s0: RSN: pre-authentication with 5c:5b:35:6f:19:97 failed
```

These are the details of my hardware

```
(base) snappy@thesunny:~$ sudo uname -a
Linux thesunny 5.4.0-89-generic #100~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 29 10:59:42 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) snappy@thesunny:~$ ifconfig

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.182.117.187  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.182.255.255
        inet6 fe80::6773:ee0c:cc14:95ad  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1e:64:e4:26:31  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14339  bytes 13002945 (13.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11435  bytes 1805670 (1.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So the next thing I tried was changing the version of kernel. I tried couple of different version from the latest ones to the old ones, but the problem still persisted. Next I downgraded to ubuntu 18.04 with a clean install and the problem still persists.
Should I try to update the wifi driver?

Comment: I don't think the freezing is because of wifi, disconnect some USB devices

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have a usb mouse which i disconnected but I still faced the same issue.

Comment: Then there might be a problem with your sd card reader as it is connecting and disconnecting a lot

Comment: I didn't realize it was the sd card reader until you mentioned, so i tried to remove the hardware but unfortunately two of my screws won't budge so couldn't reach to the physical hardware. So for now I have disabled the hardware using the command mentioned here [link](https://karlcode.owtelse.com/blog/2017/01/09/disabling-usb-ports-on-linux/), I hope it works, will update. Thank you!

Comment: @snapshot Do you have an update on this lock up problem?